# Fractional Number of Days between DateTime objects in Java

Tags: java, jodatime

How do I find the fractional difference in Days between two Joda-Time DateTime instances?

Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays() gives me a round number like 10/15 etc. What i need to get is exact value like 10.15 or 15.78

Comment: Use `Hours.hoursBetween`, `getHours` and divide by `24.0`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis your idea is sweet/simple. With minimal changes :)

Comment: In date time work, such fractions are not commonly used. So no such function. Note that Joda-Time provides three classes to represent a span of time in various ways: [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), and [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html). These classes can parse and generate [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard strings such as `PT3H30M` for three and a half hours.

Comment: That's not...100% well-defined, is part of the issue.  If some of the days have leapseconds, or DST changes, what does that even mean for the definition of a fractional day?

Answer (score 1):

You might miss minutes due to the round off, if you use Hours.hoursBetween .

Try this :
 (end.getMillis - start.getMillis() )/(1000*3600*24)

Answer (score 1):

To get a number of days with a fraction, calculate the difference in a small enough unit for your precision requirement, then convert to `double` before doing the division that converts to days:

```
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Copenhagen");
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(1997, 1, 1, 0, 0, zone);
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(1997, 3, 29, 12, 0, zone);

    int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(date1, date2).getSeconds();
    double days = (double) seconds / (double) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1);
    System.out.println("Difference in days is " + days);
```

This snippet outputs:

> Difference in days is 87.5

We need to supply the correct time zone to take transitions to and from summer time (DST) into account. In my example both days are in the standard time part of the year in the EU, so 12 hours translate to 0.5 days. If for `date2` I had picked a date in the beginning of April, after summer time has begun, this would not have been the case. For example:

```
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(1997, 4, 1, 12, 0, zone);
```

> Difference in days is 90.45833333333333

The code will work with a difference of up to about 68 years since an `int` only holds this many seconds. If you need a greater span of years, consider using minutes or hours instead of seconds. If you pass two dates that are too far apart, Joda-Time is friendly enough to throw an exception rather than tacitly giving you an incorrect result.

This answer was written on the occasion of [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042335/how-to-calculate-difference-in-2-input-dates-considering-time-as-well), and the example datetimes have been taken from there.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the time in millis and divide by number of millis per day:

```
double diff = (end.getMillis() - start.getMillis()) / 86400000d;
```

*Test*

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1,  0,  0,  0,   0); // Jan 1, 2015
DateTime end   = new DateTime(2015, 7, 4, 14, 23, 55, 876); // Jul 4, 2015 at 2:23:55.876 PM

final int MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 86_400_000
double diff = (double)(end.getMillis() - start.getMillis()) / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
System.out.println(diff);

int days = (int)diff;
diff = (diff - days) * 24;
int hours = (int)diff;
diff = (diff - hours) * 60;
int minutes = (int)diff;
diff = (diff - minutes) * 60;
int seconds = (int)diff;
diff = (diff - seconds) * 1000;
int millis = (int)Math.round(diff);
System.out.println(days    + " days, "    +
                   hours   + " hours, "   +
                   minutes + " minutes, " +
                   seconds + " seconds, " +
                   millis  + " millis");
```

*Output*

```
184.55828560185185
184 days, 13 hours, 23 minutes, 55 seconds, 876 millis
```

Note that it's only 13 hours, not 14, because of daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input from comments, i got it working precisely to the seconds using:

```
double days = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end).getSeconds()/86400;
```