# Duration.between() doesn't work the way I want to

Tags: java, datetime, difference, duration

I want the exact duration in hours between dates. The `between`-method seems to only consider the difference in whole hours. Why is that and what can I do/use instead?

```
Duration dur = Duration.between(
    LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 12, 00), LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 16, 45));

float durH = dur.toHours(); 

System.out.println(durH);
```

This code gives me `4.0` but what I want is `4.75`.

Comment: Do it to minutes, then divide by 60

Comment: Or do it to seconds, then devide by 60*60.

Comment: `Duration#toHours` returns a `long`. You only see it as `4.0` because you store it as `float` and it gets implicitly converted.

Comment: None of the seems to work for me. Taking minutes and dividing by 60 still returns 4. Saving as long also does nothing.

Comment: Can you show us what `toMinutes()` returns by itself?  (Also, `Duration` and `LocalDateTime` are a bit of a mismatch.  `Period` would be more appropriate -- since it matters what timezone you're in and if the duration overlaps with a time change like daylight savings.)

Comment: @HenrikLied int/int yields an int. You need to divide by 60**f** to get a float.

Comment: @HenrikLied Please don't edit your question with the solution. The answers provide it.

Comment: Similar: [Fractional Number of Days between DateTime objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574805/fractional-number-of-days-between-datetime-objects-in-java)

Comment: Those toXXX() method should return float instead of long, return an imprecise value without any warning(even not in doc) is strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine.

```
double durH = dur.toMinutes()/60.;
// or
double durH = dur.toMinutes()/60.f;

System.out.println(durH);
```

prints

```
4.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `(float) duration.toMinutes() / Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes()`

Answer (score 0):

`Duration#toHours` returns a `long`. You only see it as `4.0` because you store it as `float` and it gets implicitly converted.

What you want it to take the minutes part via `Duration#toMinutesPart`, divide it by 60 (as `float`) and add it to the hours:

```
System.out.println((dur.toHours() + dur.toMinutesPart()/60f)); // prints 4.75
```

Note that this breaks down when there is a shift in the calendar and the hour does not have 60 seconds. There are numerous instances in the world where a minute doesn't have 60 seconds - leap seconds come to mind first and foremost, but also others. Therefore, it is recommended to display such times as `4:45` and not converting them to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 12, 00), LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 16, 45));    
float hourWithDecimals = (float) duration.toMinutes() / Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes();

System.out.println(hourWithDecimals);
```

Obtaining a more precise value in minutes `duration.toMinutes()`, "cast it" to hours without using any magic number through `Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to float before division, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Duration dur = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 12, 00), LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 16, 45));

    double durh = (double)dur.toMinutes()/60;

    System.out.println(durh);
}
```

Because dur.toMinutes() return a long number.

Answer (score -2):

The method [`Duration#toHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toHours())

> [...] returns the total number of hours in the duration by dividing the number of seconds by 3600.

As the method returns the result as `long`, the fractional part is cut off.

You can get the fractional part by doing the same thing explicitly:

```java
Duration dur = Duration.between(
    LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 12, 00), LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 20, 16, 45));

double durH = dur.toSeconds() / 3600.0;

System.out.println(durH); // gives 4.75
```

You have to divide by a `double` or `float`, otherwise you have an integer division.